# Came across weird loop behaviour

Tags: c#, arrays

I feel kinda dumb, but I couldn't find a solution, so I'm asking here. The purpose of my code is to fill 2D array 4x4 with random numbers in range from 0-255 and render them to a panel. Problem is, that I have two functions: RenderArray() and WriteToTextbox(). They both return same values from the array only if one of them reads from the array as array[y,x], instead of array[x,y]. I find this behaviour rather weird and I cannot simply think of the reason why. Here's the code:

```
    private bool newRequest;
    private bool hasGenerated;
    private int[,] array = new int[4, 4];
    private static Random random = new Random();

    private void btnRandom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!HasGenerated)
        {
            HasGenerated = true;
        }

        NewRequest = true;
        pnlRandom.Refresh();
    }

    public bool NewRequest
    {
        get { return newRequest; }
        set { newRequest = value; }
    }

    public bool HasGenerated
    {
        get { return hasGenerated; }
        set { hasGenerated = value; }
    }

    public static Random GetRandom
    {
        get { return random; }
    }

    private void pnlRandom_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!HasGenerated)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (NewRequest)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
                {
                    array[x, y] = GetRandom.Next(0, 256);
                }
            }

            NewRequest = false;
        }

        RenderArray(e);
        WriteToTextbox();
    }

    private void RenderArray(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;

        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
            {
                //int color = array[y, x]; If I write it like that
                //they will return same values.
                int color = array[x, y];
                SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(color, color, color));
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x * 64, y * 64, 64, 64);

                g.FillRectangle(brush, rect);
            }
        }
    }

    private void WriteToTextbox()
    {
        txtRandom.Clear();

        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
            {
                int length = array[x, y].ToString().Length;
                txtRandom.Text += array[x, y].ToString().PadLeft(3 * 4 - length + 3 * 4 % 3);
            }

            txtRandom.Text += "\r\n";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're iterating the loops in the wrong order.

When drawing the array, it doesn't matter whether you loop through `x` or `y` first; either way, each cell will be drawn at the coordinates you pass to `FillRectangle()`.

When printing the array to a string, you write the characters in the order that you iterate them.
By looping through `x`, then `y`, you're looping through every *column* (`x`) in the array, then looping throw the cells vertically down that column (`y`).
Therefore, you're printing the array transposed.